# Get index and column of a specific value in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, indexing

I have df. As an example, I can ask the following data.

```
data = {
   "calories": [420, 380, 390],
   "duration": [50, 40, 45]
}
#load data into a DataFrame object:
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

For example, there are 380 calories in 40 minutes. What I want to ask is:
How can I locate the number "40"? So how can I see the index and column name?

```
Input: "40"
Output: "1, duration"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```py
# stack will pair the indices with column names
res = df.eq(40).replace(False, pd.NA).stack().index.values
res
# [(1, 'duration')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
df.loc[df["duration"]==40].index
```

or

```
df.loc[ np.where(df==40)[1]]
```